# How can I undo an autofill in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, undo

I used autofill to automatically complete a few fields in a form in Google Chrome. How can I undo the autofill?

Comment: chrome://settings/autofill and delete the entry which you don't want .

Comment: @Shree Thank you, I want to undo  the autofill, not delete entries

Answer (score 0):

I'd like this too. The only solutions I've found are to:
disable autofill and reload the page or
remove the autofill data for that page, and reload the page.

I wish I could limit the username/password autofill to a giving /login/etc path on the site, and NOT have that same username/password filled in when I'm doing admin and looking at another user's info.

Here is more information on Chrome auto-fill. I do not see a way to undo anywhere, but this article contains information on removing auto-fill entries for specific pages and even disabling auto-fill.

http://osxdaily.com/2018/07/20/how-delete-chrome-autofill-suggetsions/

One workaround I use is to open the site in an Incognito window. This stop auto-fill, but still gives me the option of choosing previous stored answers including credentials.

It looks like currently there is no "undo" option. :(

Comment: Thanks, typically when I want to undo autofill, it's because it has erased some of my field values and I want to retri them, rather than reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Fn-Shift-Delete` - this work for me on Chrome 75